# Array-aggregation across a link-table in Opaleye

Tags: haskell, arrows, opaleye, profunctor

I'm trying to construct an Opaleye query that matches the following SQL:

```
select * ,
    (select array_agg(tags.tagname)
     from articles_tags
     inner join tags on tags.id = articles_tags.tag_fk
         where articles_tags.article_fk = articles.id
    )
from articles
```

The tables involved (simplified) are:

```
articles: (id, title, content)
articles_tags: (article_fk, tag_fk)
tags: (id, tagname)
```

My goal is to query for articles that have one or more tags attached, and retrieve all attached tags as an array.

So far, I got the following elementary queries:

```
-- | Query all article-tag relations.
allTaggedArticlesQ :: OE.Select TaggedArticleR
allTaggedArticlesQ = OE.selectTable taggedArticlesTable

-- | Query article-tag relations for the given articles.
taggedArticlesQ :: OE.SelectArr PA.ArticleIdField TaggedArticleR
taggedArticlesQ = proc articleId -> do
  ta <- allTaggedArticlesQ -< ()
  OE.restrict -< articleFk ta .=== articleId
  returnA -< ta

-- | Join article-ids and tag names for the given subset of articles.
articleTagNamesQ :: OE.SelectArr PA.ArticleIdField ArticleTagR
articleTagNamesQ = proc articleIds -> do
  ta <- taggedArticlesQ -< articleIds
  tags <- PT.allTagsQ -< ()
  OE.restrict -< PT.tagKey tags .=== tagFk ta
  returnA -< ArticleTag (articleFk ta) (PT.tagName tags)
```

However, I cannot get the aggregation to work: The following does not type-check, and I do not understand how to compose this aggregation with the above query:

```
-- | Aggregate all tag names for all given articles
articleTagsQ :: PA.ArticleIdField -> OE.Select (PA.ArticleIdField, F (OE.SqlArray OE.SqlText))
articleTagsQ = OE.aggregate
          ( pArticleTag
              ArticleTag
                { atArticleFk = OE.groupBy,
                  atTagname = OE.arrayAgg
                }
          ) OE.selectTable articleTagNamesQ
```

In some blog posts and GitHub issues, I found a remark that the aggregation does not play nice with Product-Profunctors and Arrows and, therefore, cannot be included in an arrow query. Yet, I am relatively new to Haskell and haven't really understood the theory behind these two libraries (there does not seem to be a beginner-friendly documentation); therefore, I cannot come up with the general structure how to combine queries with aggregation. There are some examples by William Yao [here](https://gitlab.com/williamyaoh/haskell-orm-comparison/-/blob/master/opaleye-impl/src/Lib.hs), but I don't understand the general concept, so I can't apply these examples to my problem.

I would highly appreciate if someone can provide insight on how to compose aggregation with regular queries in Opaleye, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After crunching through several examples, here is the solution I finally managed to build and run:

```
import           Control.Arrow
import qualified Opaleye as OE
import qualified Data.Profunctor.Product as PP

type F field = OE.Field field 

-- | Query all tags.
allTagsQ :: OE.Select TagR
allTagsQ = OE.selectTable tagsTable

-- | Query all article-tag relations.
allTaggedArticlesQ :: OE.Select TaggedArticleR
allTaggedArticlesQ = OE.selectTable taggedArticlesTable

-- | Join article-ids and tag names for all articles.
articleTagNamesQ :: OE.Select (F OE.SqlInt8, F OE.SqlText)
articleTagNamesQ = proc () -> do
  TaggedArticle {articleFk = aId, tagFk = tFk} <- allTaggedArticlesQ -< ()
  Tag {tagKey = tId, tagName = tn} <- allTagsQ -< ()
  OE.restrict -< tFk OE.(.===) tId -- INNER JOIN ON
  returnA -< (aId, tn)

-- | Aggregate all tag names for all articles
articleTagsQ :: OE.Select (F OE.SqlInt8, F (OE.SqlArray OE.SqlText))
articleTagsQ =
  OE.aggregate (PP.p2 (OE.groupBy, OE.arrayAgg)) $
    arr (first) <<< articleTagNamesQ
```

A row of the `articles_tags` table is represented in Haskell by the polymorphic `TaggedArticle*` Opaleye type, and similarly `Tag*` for tag rows.

The key point is to select all rows of the two tables, then perform the join, and then finally do the aggregation. Because the aggregation function in Opaleye is neither an `Arrow` nor a `ProductProfunctor`, but the `OE.aggregate` function expects a `Select a`, I could not include the aggregation as part of a query written in arrow notation. Instead, I had to write a separate function that takes a `Select a` as input.

Note that aggregation cannot be performed on the more general `SelectArr`. From the pacakge documentation: *"By design there is no aggregation function of type `Aggregator b b' -> \S.SelectArr a b -> S.SelectArr a b'` . Such a function would allow violation of SQL's scoping rules and lead to invalid queries."*

My code above is somewhat simplified. I tried to use polymorphic types for keys. However, I could not figure out how to write all code in terms of these newtype wrappers; instead, I had to unwrap and rewrap the fields several times.

Another issue I ran into was the definition of the row type that results from the JOIN. Initially, I defined a new polymorphic row type. But then I did not manage to properly unwrap the fields of that type so I could feed them into the `OE.Aggregator`. Therefore, I settled for the more verbose tuple notation above.

Comment: Hello Ulrich, it looks like a working answer. You are welcome to ask such questions on the Opaleye issue tracker (https://github.com/tomjaguarpaw/haskell-opaleye/issues/new) where you will generally get a quicker response and useful discussion (discussion is generally forbidden on StackOverflow).

Regarding wrapping and unwrapping, can you please come and explain the problem on the issue tracker via the link above and I will help you out.

Comment: (By the way, instead of `arr (first)` you can just write `arr first`, and that is in fact the same as just `first`.

Comment: (But it seems the `first` needs to be removed for it to compile anyway. See my separate answer.)

Comment: For those interested, this discussion continued on https://github.com/tomjaguarpaw/haskell-opaleye/issues/479

Answer (score 1):

I've made a few changes to the code in your answer so that it compiles as a standalone file:

- The operator needed to be `OE..===` rather than `OE.(.===)`
- The `arr first` needed to be removed
- I added some data type definitions, table definitions, and extensions

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import           Control.Arrow
import qualified Opaleye as OE
import qualified Data.Profunctor.Product as PP
import           Data.Profunctor.Product.TH (makeAdaptorAndInstance')

type F field = OE.Field field

data TaggedArticle a b = TaggedArticle { articleFk :: a, tagFk :: b }
type TaggedArticleR = TaggedArticle (F OE.SqlInt8) (F OE.SqlInt8)

data Tag a b = Tag { tagKey :: a, tagName :: b }
type TagR = Tag (F OE.SqlInt8) (F OE.SqlText)

$(makeAdaptorAndInstance' ''TaggedArticle)
$(makeAdaptorAndInstance' ''Tag)

tagsTable :: OE.Table TagR TagR
tagsTable = error "Fill in the definition of tagsTable"

taggedArticlesTable :: OE.Table TaggedArticleR TaggedArticleR
taggedArticlesTable = error "Fill in the definition of taggedArticlesTable"

-- | Query all tags.
allTagsQ :: OE.Select TagR
allTagsQ = OE.selectTable tagsTable

-- | Query all article-tag relations.
allTaggedArticlesQ :: OE.Select TaggedArticleR
allTaggedArticlesQ = OE.selectTable taggedArticlesTable

-- | Join article-ids and tag names for all articles.
articleTagNamesQ :: OE.Select (F OE.SqlInt8, F OE.SqlText)
articleTagNamesQ = proc () -> do
  TaggedArticle {articleFk = aId, tagFk = tFk} <- allTaggedArticlesQ -< ()
  Tag {tagKey = tId, tagName = tn} <- allTagsQ -< ()
  OE.restrict -< tFk OE..=== tId -- INNER JOIN ON
  returnA -< (aId, tn)

-- | Aggregate all tag names for all articles
articleTagsQ :: OE.Select (F OE.SqlInt8, F (OE.SqlArray OE.SqlText))
articleTagsQ =
  OE.aggregate (PP.p2 (OE.groupBy, OE.arrayAgg)) articleTagNamesQ
```